# Error: Compile Error: invalid ID field: Cus_obj_Record_ID at line 40 column 22

Tags: apex

Hi Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error.

Code:

public class LeadConversion {

```
public PageReference RedirecttoLead()     {
    String currentLead = '/' + siteObj.Id;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(currentLead);
    return pageRef;
 }

 private Site__c siteObj,temp_siteObj;
public ID Cus_Account_ID;
public ID Cus_obj_Record_ID;
// The extension constructor initializes the private member
// variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
// controller.
public LeadConversion(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
 {
 System.debug('******Voltum******');
         siteObj = (Site__c)stdController.getRecord();
         Cus_obj_Record_ID = siteObj.Id;
}

public void convertLead(){

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = siteObj.Name;
    acc.CurrencyIsoCode = siteObj.CurrencyIsoCode;

    try 
   { 
    insert acc; 
   }
    Catch (Exception ex1)
    {        
     ex1.getmessage();
    }
    Contact cc = new Contact();
    cc.LastName = siteObj.LastName__c;

    temp_siteObj=[select AccountId from contact where Id ='Cus_obj_Record_ID'];
    Cus_Account_ID = temp_siteObj;
    cc.AccountId= Cus_Account_ID;
   // cc.accountId = siteObj.Name;
    //Id accountId = [select AccountId from Contact where Id = {ID}][0].AccountId; 
    //System.Debug(accountId);

   try 
   { 
    insert cc; 
   }
    Catch (Exception ex2)
    {

     ex2.getmessage();
    }



}

}
```

Waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
temp_siteObj=[select AccountId from contact where Id ='Cus_obj_Record_ID'];
```

you are passing a string literal where an id field is expected.  Looking at your code, it appears that the property 'Cus_obj_Record_ID' should contain an ID, in which case you can bind it in to the SOQL as follows:

```
temp_siteObj=[select AccountId from contact where Id =:Cus_obj_Record_ID];
```

This does assume that there will always be a record returned, which won't be the case if Cus_obj_Record_ID is null - if that is a possibility its better to assign the results to a list and check if there are are records matching, e.g.

```
List<Contact> conts=[select AccountId from contact where Id =:Cus_obj_Record_ID];
if (conts.size()>0)
{
   temp_siteObj=conts[0];
   // rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue - 
 **System.debug('LEAD ID' + ar.get('LEADID'));
                String tempLeadId = (string)ar.get('LEADID');
                String leadQuery = 'SELECT LEAD.ID,XYZ__c from LEAD where LEAD.ID =   tempLeadId ;**

here it happened that the LEADID had leading 0s, which were getting omitted in SOQL formation string.

Modified it to have single quotes wrapping the LEADID. It worked then.

**System.debug('LEAD ID' + ar.get('LEADID'));
                String tempLeadId = (string)ar.get('LEADID');
                String leadQuery = 'SELECT LEAD.ID,Delete_Lead_Response_Date__c from LEAD where LEAD.ID = \''+  tempLeadId +'\'';**